# Populate table with Parse database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm working on an iOS app, which pulls data from a Parse database to populate a table view. I can get data from the database to print to the log, but when I try to use the data to populate the table cells, it just does not work. The table is empty every time and I can't figure out why. Any thoughts?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var promoNum = -1

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var titles = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var getPromosQuery = PFQuery(className: "Promotions")
        getPromosQuery.whereKey("zip", equalTo: "85281")
        getPromosQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    self.titles.append(object["title"] as! String)

                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return titles.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let promoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell

        promoCell.promotionTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        return promoCell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        promoNum = indexPath.row
        return indexPath
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I just needed to add `self.tableView.reloadData()` after `self.titles.append(object["title"] as! String)`.

Comment: But you have to make sure you call `reloadData` on the main thread. Never make UI calls on a background thread. And make sure your call to `reloadData` is after the whole `for` loop, not inside.